# GridView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

i'm trying to do this page[image]

but what i  get is this
[image]

this is my code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            width: 230,
            height: 40,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {

              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor:
                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xff28CC61)),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Add a book", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20
                ),),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text("Explore between 10 books", style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20
          ),),
        ),
        Container(
          //adding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    childAspectRatio: 1,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8),
                itemCount: books.length,


                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {



                  return Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Card(

                      color: Color(0xFFEDEDED),
                      child: Column(

                        children: [


                          Image.asset(books[index].image, height: 150
                            ,
                            width: 150,fit: BoxFit.cover,),

                        ],


                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),


      ],
    ),
  ),
```

ignore the colors and styles i want how to do the page
i stucked on gridview and how to write text below the picture + How can I fix my code to do it? So each image has same size as others? i tried to see the grid view documentation and i could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change childAspectRatio : 1 to `childAspectRatio:0.7`. childaspectRatio defines the ratio between width and height of children. If you set it as 1 you will get a square shaped widget. More than 1 is horizontal rectangle and less than 1 gives vertical rectangle.